# how can get php two array value

Tags: php, arrays

I have theese two arrays:

```
$arr_1 = array('a','b','c','d');
$arr_2 = array('e','f','g','h');
```

Now I want to get the value in the following format:

```
a:e
b:f
c:g
d:h
```

How can I do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

$arr_1 = array('a','b','c','d');
$arr_2 = array('e','f','g','h');

$array3 = array_combine($arr_1, $arr_2);
foreach($array3 as $key=>$val){
echo $key.":".$val."<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`array_combine()`](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_combine.asp) for this:

```
$arr_1 = array(a,b,c,d);
$arr_2 = array(e,f,g,h);
$result = array_combine($arr_1, $arr_2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// First, ensure they are the same length    
if(count($arr_1) == count($arr_2)){

  // Then combine them into associative array
  $combined_array = array_combine($arr_1, $arr_2);

  // Check the array is not empty
  if(!empty($combined_array)){

    // Print them out (alternatively put them in an array)
    foreach($combined_array as $key => $value){
      echo $key . ":" . $value . "<br>";
    }
  }
}
```